# ¿Cómo guardar una imagen capturada por la cámara, dentro de un view? React Native - Expo

Tags: react-native, programación-móvil, redux, expo

REACT NATIVE / EXPO

Logro acceder a la cámara, capturar la imagen, la guardo en un modal, pero luego quiero guardar la imagen dentro de un View que está posicionado justo antes de la cámara, es decir: estoy en una pantalla donde tengo el view (fondo blanco con un icono de cámara en el centro), al darle clic al icono de cámara me abre la cámara.

Lo que deseo es que en el modal pueda confirmar que quiero guardar esa imagen, y esa imagen me aparezca como "fondo" del view en vez del fondo blanco. Intente de algunas formas y no logré hacerlo

Aquí les adjunto mis códigos:

Pantalle donde se encuentra el view:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
//actions
import IconClose from '../helpers/iconAction';
import IconCameraScanner from '../helpers/simpleIconAction';
import FinalizeEntry from '../helpers/viewAction';
import '../images/check.jpg'

import CameraAndroid from './AndroidCameraScreen';



export default class ScannerScreen extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
        return (
                
            <View style={styles.containerScanner}>
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.header}>
                        <IconClose
                            iconName="close"
                            screenName="Home"
                            iconSize={33}
                            iconColor="white"
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.titleHeader}>{`Escanee el frente \n y dorso del cheque`}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.cameras}>
                        <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
                            <ImageBackground 
                                style={{ 
                                    width: '100%', 
                                    height: '100%',
                                    flexDirection: 'column',
                                    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                                    alignItems: 'flex-end'
                                }} 
                                source={require('../images/check.jpg')}
                            >
                            <IconCameraScanner 
                                iconName="camera" 
                                iconSize={40} 
                                iconColor="#5095DC" 
                                screenName="CameraAndroid"
                            />
                            </ImageBackground>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
                            
                            <IconCameraScanner 
                                iconName="camera" 
                                iconSize={50} 
                                iconColor="#97bcff" 
                                screenName="CameraAndroid"
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.containerFinalize}>
                    <FinalizeEntry 
                        screenName="ScannedChecks" 
                        textButton="FINALIZAR INGRESO" 
                        iconName="arrowright"
                        iconSize={24}
                        iconColor="#82C5FE"
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Abajo se encuentran los estilos que no creí necesario adjuntarlos. El view que les digo es el que tiene style={styles.cameraContainer} (Hay uno con una imagen, es una prueba que hice)

Y aquí mi codigo de la cámara:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, Modal, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import GoBack from '../helpers/viewAction';

import ScannerScreen from './ScannerScreen';

export default function App(props) {

  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const camRef = useRef(null);
  const [capturedPhoto, setCapturedPhoto] = useState(null)
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted')
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <View 
            style={{
              height: '100%', 
              flexDirection: 'column', 
              justifyContent: 'center', 
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}
          >
      <Text 
        style={{ 
          textAlign: 'center', 
          fontSize: 24, 
          color: '#61B5FC',
          marginBottom: '15%'
          }} 
        > {`No has aceptado \n el permiso \n de acceso a la cámara`} </Text>
      <GoBack 
          screenName="Scanner" 
          textButton="VOLVER " 
          iconName="back"
          iconSize={24}
          iconColor="#82C5FE"
      />
      </View>;
  }

  async function takePicture() {
    if(camRef) {
      const data = await camRef.current.takePictureAsync();
      setCapturedPhoto(data.uri);
      setOpen(true);
      console.log(data);
    }
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Camera 
        style={{ flex: 1 }} 
        type={type} 
        ref={camRef}
      >
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          flexDirection: 'row'
        }}>
      </View>
      <View 
        style={{ 
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'space-between'
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ 
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0 ,0 ,0 ,0.5)',
            height: '37%',
            width: '100%'
          }}
        ></View>
        <View style={{ 
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0 ,0 ,0 ,0.5)',
            height: '37%',
            width: '100%',
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity 
            style={{ 
              justifyContent: 'center', 
              alignItems: 'center',
              width: 70
            }} 
            onPress={ takePicture } 
          >
            <View style={{ 
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderRadius: 50,
              borderColor: '#fff',
              height: 70,
              width: 70,
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              marginBottom: 20
            }}
            >
              <View style={{
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderRadius: 50,
                borderColor: '#fff',
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                backgroundColor: '#fff'}} 
              >
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>    
      </View>
      </Camera>

      { capturedPhoto &&
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={open}
      >
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', margin: 15}}>
          
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ margin: 10 }} onPress={ () => setOpen(false)}>
            <AntDesign name="closecircleo" size={50} color="#ff0000" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ margin: 10 }} /* onPress={ () => setOpen(false)} */>
            <AntDesign name="checkcircleo" size={50} color="#07D532" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

          <Image 
            style={{ width: '100%', height: 180, borderRadius: 10}}
            source={{ uri: capturedPhoto }}
          />

        </View>
      </Modal>
      }          

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

El modal que les mencioné se abre al final del código, al capturar la imagen.

Espero haya expresado bien lo que deseaba.

Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que deberías hacer es pasarle una callback al componente que saca la foto. En el componente que queres tener la foto, podrias tener en el state la uri de la imagen (inicialmente vacía) y la callback seria un setState de este campo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, tu respuesta se asemeja mas a un comentario.

Comment: Tenes razón, pero me pide reputación para dejar un comentario y no la tengo :(

Comment: Muchas gracias, yo estoy probando hacerlo con redux ya que la app pretendemos agrandarla futuramente, pero estoy teniendo muchos inconvenientes. 
Creo que la tendré que manejar como lo dices.
Cualquier cosa le aviso.
Desde ya, muchas gracias !